# Reading a Serialized object from file

Tags: java, serialization

I am writing a program that requires me to write and read back an object that I created. When I'm trying to read back in the object and Deserialize it, I am getting an *Ilegal start of expression* error. I was wondering if someone can tell me what this is an how I can solve it.

```
        RandomAccessFile temp = new RandomAccessFile(fileSystemName,"r");
        this.numberOfDirectories= temp.readInt();
        this.fileSystemSize = temp.readInt();
        this.numberOfBlocks = temp.readInt();
        //Prepares and loads the bitMap
        numberOfBytes = (numberOfBlocks/8)+1;
        //directory = new Directory(numberOfDirectories);
        bitMap = new byte[numberOfBytes];
        for(int i=0;i<numberOfBytes;i++)bitMap[i]=temp.readByte();
        temp.close();
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(fileSystemName);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fin);

        //File file = new File(fileSystemName);
        System.out.println(bitMap.length);
        offset = 12 + numberOfBytes;
        //ois.skipBytes(offset);
        //Read Directories
        directory = <Directory> ois.readObject();
```

The offset is because I am first using a RandomAccessFile object to read in some integers and chars first. I appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: try running the application wihtout ois.skipBytes(offset)

Comment: Does your code compile? Sounds like a syntactical error. Maybe you have missed a bracket somewhere?

Comment: Could you post part of the stack trace, and your code that writes to the file too? The trick with these is often matching output with input

Comment: 'Apr 16, 2012 1:18:46 AM fsystem1.FileSystem <init>
SEVERE: null
java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 0000001E
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:801)
 at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:298)
 at fsystem1.FileSystem.<init>(FileSystem.java:46)
 at fsystem1.FSystem1.main(FSystem1.java:29)
'

Comment: Yes - this is an error in the object stream header, meaning the first bytes its reading in are incorrect. So I agree with @UNNI - the offset is suspicious, so check that. If you can post more code we can help further.

Comment: I added more code in the question.

Comment: Which is it? "Illegal start of expression error", which is a compile error, or "java.io.StreamCorruptedException", which is a runtime problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use one stream then you don't need to worry about offsets, and make sure you're reading what you're writing. e.g the following works fine:

```
final String name = "tmp.data";
int numberOfDirectories = 2;
int fileSystemSize = 4;
byte[] bitMap = new byte[] { 0, 1, 0 };
File someObject = new File(".");
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name));
outputStream.write(numberOfDirectories);
outputStream.write(fileSystemSize);
outputStream.write(bitMap.length);
outputStream.write(bitMap);
outputStream.writeObject(someObject);
outputStream.close();
// ....
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(name));
System.out.println("numberOfDirectories:" + inputStream.read());
System.out.println("fileSystemSize:" + inputStream.read());
final int size = inputStream.read();
byte[] readBitMap = new byte[size];
inputStream.read(readBitMap);
System.out.println("bitMap:" + readBitMap);
System.out.println("someObject:" + inputStream.readObject());
inputStream.close();
```

Furthermore, to make life even easier, I'd be tempted to create a class that represents all the data you want to store in the file, then the Object stream takes care of everything for you:

```
public static class Data {
    private int numberOfDirectories;
    private int fileSystemSize;
    private byte[] bitMap;
    private File someObject;
    // getters and setters .... 
}

final String name = "tmp.data";
Data data = new Data();
data.setNumberOfDirectories(2);
data.setFileSystemSize(4);
data.setBitMap(new byte[] { 0, 1, 0 });
data.setSomeObject(new File("."));
ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name));
outputStream.writeObject(data);
outputStream.close();
// ....
ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(name));
Data readData = (Data) inputStream.readObject();
System.out.println("numberOfDirectories:" + readData.getNumberOfDirectories());
System.out.println("fileSystemSize:" + readData.getFileSystemSize());
System.out.println("bitMap:" + readData.getBitMap());
System.out.println("someObject:" + readData.getSomeObject());
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: Well the thing is its that I have to keep the size that I am outputting this a constant size. As far as I have looked, only RandomAccessFile lets me do this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the data in a comptible manner with how you wrote it.

An Object stream has a specific format. It has a header and it has lost of byte around the bytes you are interested in. e.g. if you write one `Integer` it will take 88 bytes.  You can't just read within an Object stream and access bits of it randomly or skip bytes are expect it to work.

How did you write the data?

Comment: You mean that I have to make sure that I read what I had written first, then read in the object?

Comment: I mean you have to read in a manner consistent with what you wrote. Unless you use skip when writing, its highly unlikely to will know where to skip to when reading.